# What is the model of the car in this photo?

Tags: photo-identification, photo, 1920s, texas

This photo is from 1925 in Big Lake, Reagan, Texas.  Can anyone tell what the make of the vehicle is? Photo is Developed by Sun Company, Kodak Finishers, San Antonio, TX with number 217 stamped on back and caption on back: Mary Jo 1925.[image]

Comment: Vehicle identification questions crop up on http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/  You may get an answer there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a [Ford Model T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_Model_T) Coupe, produced from 1917-1927 Looking through some various [model year images here](http://www.american-automobiles.com/Ford/1924-Ford.html), seems to narrow it to 1923-25 by location of the hinges and how the door swings. Before 1923 the door hinges appear to be located on the other side of the door, with the handle near the window edge. The 1924 model seems to show the raised portion(vent intake?) near the center of the window , matching the photo. The hood ornament, though indistinct, also appears to match general Model-T designs.

The curious part I can't seem to match is the X shaped grill/radiator protector on the front.  This doesn't appear in any other images I've seen, so may have been an optional accessory, or a custom add on to protect the radiator from rocks?  Your other photo also seems to have the same object, which would appear to strengthen the link between the two images.