# What year is this photo likely taken?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, photo-identification, texas

I've got a glossy photo that measures 3"×4.75" of a man near [Devil's River, Texas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devils_River_(Texas)) with a car in the background.[image]
The back of the photo has a blue `10` on it from the film processing.[image]
What is the approximate date this photograph appears to have been taken?  Does anyone know what kind of car is in the background?

Does the car appear to be the same one from the 1925 photograph in [What is the model of the car in this photo?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/10703)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The present picture is hardly crisp, but we can compare the two car photos at similar scales:
[image: Old car photos side by side]

There are certainly some consistencies between the two cars, notably the shade/flap above the windscreen, the wheels and arches, and possibly the door hinges. Nothing absolutely conclusive, but they look pretty similar to me, and could be the same car.

I can't identify the car after a quick search, but it  looks fairly typical of the 1920s overall. There's no logo visible, and the hood ornament isn't very clear, although the upright structure is quite distinctive. The cars are fairly similar to various Ford Model T Coupe designs from ~1918-1926, and a couple of Buick models of a similar vintage, but none of the details (hinges, vents, grille etc) seem to match perfectly. In particular, the left image has a crossed structure over the radiator grille, and I haven't seen anything similar. Perhaps it wasn't a standard feature. As suggested before, https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/ might be a better bet, or a classic car enthusiast forum is likely to identify the car fairly quickly.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a Model T. Glossy photos became popular in the 1920's. I would guess the photo is between 1925 and 1935. Do you know the age of the man?

Comment: Rusty, if you've got some firm information to flesh out your guess, please add it.  As is, this is a very low-quality answer.

Comment: Even a link to a couple references for comparison such as a photo of a similar model T and glossy photo timeline reference would be helpful.. otherwise we might convert this to a comment.

Comment: I know the man in the photo, just not his age when this was taken.